# Can I extract who is speaking in a gmeet/teams using websocket?

Tags: web, websocket, puppeteer, microsoft-teams, google-meet

I am working on a bot to record gmeet, teams meeting and zoom.
I am currently doing diarization using deep learning open-source libraries, but the results are far from good.
I wanted to know if I could extract from the websocket information like when someone is talking, so I could make my diarization without using deep learning.
Do you know if I could extract that information? With what kind of tool? My bots are made using puppeteer.
In the best case scenario, I could extract audio by user, in an ok one I can extract it by timeframe.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Microsoft Teams does provide the capability for a bot to identify which meeting participants are currently speaking. This is done through the concept of Active speakers and Dominant speakers. Active speakers identify which participants are being heard in each received audio frame. Dominant speakers identify which participants are currently most active or dominant in the group conversation, though their voice isn't heard in every audio frame.

Comment: Thanks @Sayali-MSFT. By microsoft provide, what do you mean? How can I get the Active and Dominant speaker?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Teams platform does not provide a direct way to extract audio by user or by timeframe. However, you can fetch transcripts and recordings of a meeting using the meeting ID and the user ID of the meeting organizer, also known as organizer ID, with the Graph REST APIs.